# Render pug template from string?

Tags: node.js, string, templates, express, pug

Is it posible to render a html-page with pug template as a string?
In nodejs you can generate a html- page with a "pug tempalte" like here:

```
var express = require('express')  
var app = express()  
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
var mytemplate="html\n\thead\n\tbody";
app.get('/', function (req, res) {  
    res.render(
        'index',
        { title: 'Hey Hey Hey!', message: 'Yo Yo'})
})

app.listen(3000, function () {  
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

the template file should be in ./views/index.pug.

is it posible to use the template saved in "mytemplate" -variable instead of the file content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pug.render()`](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#pugrendersource-options-callback):

```
const pug = require('pug');
...
app.get('/', function (req, res) {  
  res.send( pug.render(mytemplate, { title: 'Hey Hey Hey!', message: 'Yo Yo'}) ) );
})
```

Or you can pre-compile your template using [`pug.compile()`](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#pugcompilesource-options), which would be a bit faster, performance-wise:

```
var mytemplate = pug.compile("html\n\thead\n\tbody");

app.get('/', function (req, res) {  
  res.send( mytemplate({ title: 'Hey Hey Hey!', message: 'Yo Yo'}) );
})
```

Comment: By the way: you used the "const" keyword, is there a significant difference to "var"?

Comment: @AlexanderTyuryaev `const` prevents re-assignment of the variable, it's a bit more strict that way, which I find better for module references :)

Comment: It works! Now i can develop my web application directly in browser